# How do I untrack a file with gitignore on live server

Tags: git

I have a file like config/config.yml that was in my repo. Meaning it is also in my local machine and live server.

Now I am trying to untrack it. So on my local I add the file to .gitignore then run
`git rm --cached config/config.yml`
Then commit it and push to repo.

Now the problem when I run `git pull` on my live machine, i got the following error.

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        config/credentials.yml.enc
        public/storage
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
```

So how do i untrack the file on server? Because I don't want to create a commit on live server.

Answer (score 0):

- First and foremost: keep a copy of that file on your live server, in an adequate directory (an *untracked* one) with the adequate access rights.

Something as basic as:

```
mkdir config.bak
chmod o-rwx config.bak
cp -t config.bak/ config/*

# if needed:
# chown -R [user]:[group] config.bak
```

should work.

It would be even safer to create that directory out of the versioned directory altogether (e.g: `$HOME/myapp/config.bak`)

- You may want to do something similar for your `public/storage` directory (I assume it is a directory ?).

Perhaps you want to move it instead of copying it, and place a symlink in its original location ?

---

Once you have placed those files in a secure place (and double checked that the content is ok and your app is still running):

just write a script which removes the offending items, runs `git pull`, then copies the items back in place.

note: you can *test* that script by first running it on a *copy* of your production directory.